# Google map overlay update technique

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a circle on the a map that I need to update, here is one way to do it:

```
circleopts.radius=100*distance;
// delete old circle overlay
circle.setMap(null);
// create new circle overlay
circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleopts);
// display new circle overlay
circle.setMap(map);
```

For some reason I don't find this very elegant. Is that the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Circle), you should just be able to do this

```
circle.setOptions( circleopts );
```